# How to do select with where clause using JPA CrudRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hello I would like create a method to execute the follow query

```
SELECT * FROM Customer where customer.customerpremium=true;
```

I tired implement this method but not working.

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, String>{

    Iterable<Customer> findByCustomerPremium(boolean customerpremium);
}
```

follow my Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "customerid")
    private Integer customerid;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "customername")
    private String customername;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "customeremail")
    private String customeremail;

    @Column(name = "customerpremium")
    private boolean customerpremium;

    /**gets and sets*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your property is in small case `customerpremium`

try

```
Iterable<Customer> findByCustomerpremium(boolean customerpremium);
```

currently this method

`Iterable<Customer> findByCustomerPremium(boolean customerpremium);`

creating query like this

```
SELECT * FROM Customer where customer.customer_premium=:customerpremium;
```

also you can log your sql queries by adding below line in `application.properties` file

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```